# Is extension by compound definitions still conservative?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In first order logic extension by definition provides a way to conservatively extend a theory.

To define a $n$-ary function symbol $f$ we have to prove that $\forall x_1,\ldots, x_n:\exists y: \psi(y,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and then can add the axiom $\forall x_1, \ldots , x_n: \psi(f(x_1,\ldots, x_n), x_1,\ldots, x_n)$.

What if I want to decompose the new function symbol into multiple new symbols. So instead of defining $f$, I add two new symbols $a,b$ and the axiom

$\forall x_1, x_2,x_3: \psi(a(b(x_1,x_2),x_3), x_1,x_2,x_3)$

then later when I define a new compound function symbol I can reuse $a,b$ iff the defined compound terms do not overlap (overlap as in a term rewriting system sense).

So for example add the new axiom (after the appropriate existence theorem has been proven)

$\forall x_1, x_2,x_3: \psi(a(a(x_1,x_2),x_3), x_1,x_2,x_3)$

**Question:** Is this still conservative extension?

My greatest concern is with a statement like

$a(x,y) \implies \top$

which is provable but has no counterpart in the original language (but that seems to not be a requirement for conservative extension)

Comment: What are you proposing as "the appropriate existence theorem"? How are you proposing to express the relationship between the functions $a$ and $b$ in this theorem.

Comment: you prove two theorems enabling us to introduce two new ternary function symbols, now instead of adding $f,g$ you add $a,b$ and the two axioms where instead of $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ you write $a(a(x,y),z)$ and $a(b(x,y),z)$

Comment: But what are the two theorems you are proposing? And how do they express the relationships between $a$ and $b$? You are focussing on the new axioms and not on the meaning of the theorems that justify the new axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the question is whether, after proving the existence condition for $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, one can conservatively add $\psi(a(b(x_1,x_2),x_3),x_1,x_2,x_3)$ instead of the usual $\psi(f(x_1,x_2,x_3),x_1,x_2,x_3)$. The answer is no. The point is that, in a finite structure whose universe $A$ consists of $n\geq2$ elements, $\psi$ might describe a ternary operation $J$ such that all $n^2$ of the functions $x_3\mapsto J(p,q,x_3)$ (for $p,q\in A$) are different. But $x_3\mapsto a(b(p,q),x_3)$ can describe only $n$ functions, because there are only $n$ values for $b(p,q)$. So your proposed $\psi(a(b(x_1,x_2),x_3),x_1,x_2,x_3)$ might be inconsistent even when $\psi(f(x_1,x_2,x_3),x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is consistent.

I'm not sure I understand the later part of your question, but it seems to be adding the additional information that $a$ can serve in place of $b$. That won't be conservative in general, even over the previously extended theory, but maybe the non-conservativity of the previously extended theory makes the later question moot.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, in a finite universe, you cannot generally write a ternary function $f(x,y,z)$ as composite function like $a(b(x,y),z)$, what if we drop the finiteness of the universe?

Comment: @Adam In an infinite universe $A$, it's possible to write any ternary function as $a(b(x,y),z)$ provided you have the axiom of choice available. Take $b$ to be any bijection between $A\times A$ and $A$ (that's where you need the axiom of choice to ensure that the cardinalities agree), and then define $a(w,z)$ to be $f(x,y,z)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the unique pair satisfying $b(x,y)=w$.

Comment: As an aside: the conservative extension principle that the OP starts with from depends on AC. Without AC, the theorem justifying the definition needs to assert unique existence.

Comment: @RobArthan The natural model-theoretic proof of conservativity uses AC, but the result can (unless I'm overlooking something) be proved without AC, either by a proof-theoretic argument or by showing that it's absolute (so AC can be eliminated from the proof).

Comment: I don't think that's right. In fact. the OP's principle **isn't** conservative but just consistent. In ZF (not ZFC), take $\psi(x, y)$ to be $x \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow y \in x$ and use the principle to define a global choice function $f$ such that $x \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow f(x) \in x$. That's definitely not conservative over ZF. (I concede that you probably can prove the principle is consistent proof-theoretically.)

Comment: and what about constants? do i have to require unique existence to not accidently imply AC?

Comment: I think constants are fine by a  simple proof-theoretic argument.

Comment: @RobArthan It's conservative over ZF (without AC) to adjoin a new function symbol $f$ with the axiom $x\neq\varnothing\implies f(x)\in x$. What isn't conservative is to also add new instances of the replacement and/or separation schemas involving the new symbol $f$. (Those new instances of schemas would let you prove AC.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass: yes, I am sure you are right. I am too used to thinking about these issues  in the context of higher-order logic. Adam: apologies for muddying the water.